# Android get screenshot of all ListView items

Tags: android, screenshot

```
View v = rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
if (v != null) {
    v.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, dummyMatrix, null);
    v.destroyDrawingCache();   
}
```

I have this code. But I need to screenshot all my ListView items, but if my listview's have more items than visible on the screen, this code don't capture when the items bigger than the visible rect.

How to capture my ListView correctly?

**NEW WORKING CODE CREATED BY ME**

```
public static Bitmap getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap() {

    ListView listview    = MyActivity.mFocusedListView;
    ListAdapter adapter  = listview.getAdapter(); 
    int itemscount       = adapter.getCount();
    int allitemsheight   = 0;
    List<Bitmap> bmps    = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {

        View childView      = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
        childView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
        childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        childView.buildDrawingCache();
        bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());
        allitemsheight+=childView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    Bitmap bigbitmap    = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas bigcanvas    = new Canvas(bigbitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
        Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
        bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
        iHeight+=bmp.getHeight();

        bmp.recycle();
        bmp=null;
    }


    return bigbitmap;
}
```

Comment: waiting for the answer to this question.

Comment: @Sharath check my updated code: getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap() function

Comment: The code just gave a blank back screen as output

Comment: My code is working on my custom listview/listadapter on my samsung galaxy s2. Do u tried in a custom listview/adapter?

Comment: no am working for a simple listview.

Comment: yes the code is working to get a screen shot of listview but the background remains a black one even though i used a white background for the listview. Can you suggest me lacas

Comment: yeah I dont know why, maybe the FILL_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT and textview LayoutParams, etc parameters not running down before drawing it to the cache...

Comment: @Sharath check out my new working code "NEW WORKING CODE CREATED BY ME"  it is now working!!!

Comment: Am sorry to say this lacas. It didnt work for me yet. :( . I am getting the black background where the background of my sample is white. :(

Comment: maybe your Views background is transparent

Comment: Hey I have tried your code with my listview but its throwing an error like: 04-23 09:06:16.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4928): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.CustomizedListView‌​}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0 Can you give me any solution about this error?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

working code:

```
public static Bitmap getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap() {

    ListView listview    = MyActivity.mFocusedListView;
    ListAdapter adapter  = listview.getAdapter(); 
    int itemscount       = adapter.getCount();
    int allitemsheight   = 0;
    List<Bitmap> bmps    = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {

        View childView      = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
        childView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
        childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        childView.buildDrawingCache();
        bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());
        allitemsheight+=childView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    Bitmap bigbitmap    = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas bigcanvas    = new Canvas(bigbitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
        Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
        bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
        iHeight+=bmp.getHeight();

        bmp.recycle();
        bmp=null;
    }


    return bigbitmap;
}
```

Comment: Hello there, I tried to implement your code to my application, but I got issues. One is the large bitmap just draw only first element in the array, the other is I got the "trying to using recycle bitmap" when using bmp.recycle(). Can you help me? For detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044984/android-combine-many-bitmaps-to-one-large-one-goes-wrong-and-cant-recycle-bitma?noredirect=1#comment31640898_21044984

Comment: Here MyActivity.mFocusedListView; what it mFocusedListview ??

Comment: can we use same thing on gridview? i have tried but its give me nullpointer at  bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint); any idea?

Comment: @lolyoshi your issue "trying to using recycle bitmap" can be resolved by commenting bmp.recycle, As android not allows to reuse recycled bitmap

Comment: Nice. Ported this to Xamarin C# and it works a treat

Comment: Hey @lacas I have tried your code with my listview but its throwing an error like: 04-23 09:06:16.224: E/AndroidRuntime(4928): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.CustomizedListView}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0     Can you give me any solution about this error?

Comment: Thanks... Nice Answer

Comment: this code is working but there is some clarity loss. is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: If there are dynamic images in the recyclerview(images load from backend server), the screenshot will not caputure the images(show a black background), any idea to avoid this?

Answer (score 6):

While it is impossible to make a screenshot of not-yet-rendered content (like off-screen items of the ListView), you can make a multiple screenshots, scroll content between each shot, then join images. Here is a tool which can automate this for you: https://github.com/PGSSoft/scrollscreenshot

[image: illustration]

Disclaimer: I'm author of this tool, it was published by [my employer](http://www.pgs-soft.com). Feature requests are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get bitmap of your list view

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {

Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
              view.getMeasuredHeight() , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
if (bgDrawable != null)
    bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
else
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
}
```

use this as

```
Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(your listview object here);
```

and use this bitmap as you want

hope help..

Comment: not working, i am working with fragments, one fragment - one listview. this code is the same than the others...

Comment: this code is not working when list has a scroll (more elements that that are visible).

Answer (score 0):

if your generated bitmap is having black color background . this is because you view unable to fetch color from xml file. so set a color of your view

```
View v = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
            v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            v.buildDrawingCache(true);
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F08080"));
            bmps.add(v.getDrawingCache(true));
            allitemsheight += v.getMeasuredHeight();
```