# How get screenshot of all Gridview items - Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I  want to takes screenshots of entire gridview

[image]

I found same thing for a listview [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956881/1168654)

I have tried same for a gridview but not get success.

anyone help me

Comment: from below 2 ways should work.... :)