# Saving linear layout to image in Android

Tags: java, android, image, android-linearlayout

I am trying to save a page content in linear layout as an image into the storage of my phone. So I am populating a `listview` with all the attendee for certain event. Then, when my print button on click, it should save all the attendees into an image:

```
btnPrintAttendee.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            llAttendeeList.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = llAttendeeList.getDrawingCache();
            File file, f = null;
            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                file = new File(
                        android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "myfolder");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdirs();

                }
                f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + file.separator + "filename"
                        + ".png");
            }
            FileOutputStream ostream = null;
            try {
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
            try {
                ostream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

With the above code, I am able to save the linear layout as an image into a new generated folder called `myfolder`. However, for the `listview`, there is a scroll bar. So when I save the linear layout as an image, I thought it will save all the attendees into an image.

Unfortunately, it only saved the attendee on the current screen. Let's say I got 10 attendees but my list view only managed to show 5 on the current screen. The other 5 I have to scroll down. When I save linear layout to image, it only saved up the 5 attendees instead of 10.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that's not easy to do, but there is an approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742343/android-get-screenshot-of-all-listview-items. It involves compositing together bitmaps from multiple scroll states.

Comment: But then how do I save that as an image to the folder in my phone?