# Take a screenshot of RecyclerView in FULL length

Tags: java, android

I want to get a "full page" screenshot of the activity. The view contains a RecyclerView with many items.

I can take a screenshot of the current view with this function:

```
public Bitmap getScreenBitmap() {
    View v= findViewById(R.id.container).getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    v.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
    return b;
}
```

But it contains only the items I can view normally (as expected).

**Is there some way to make the RecyclerView magically show in full length (display all items at once) when I take the screenshot?**

If not, how should I approach this problem?

Comment: If you have many items, no matter if solution is possible, I guarantee you an out of memory error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Inspired from Yoav's answer. This code works for recyclerview item types and probably regardless of it's size.

It was tested with a recyclerview having linearlayout manager and three item types. Yet to check it with other layout managers.

```
public Bitmap getScreenshotFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView view) {
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = view.getAdapter();
        Bitmap bigBitmap = null;
        if (adapter != null) {
            int size = adapter.getItemCount();
            int height = 0;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            int iHeight = 0;
            final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

            // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
            final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
            LruCache<String, Bitmap> bitmaCache = new LruCache<>(cacheSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = adapter.createViewHolder(view, adapter.getItemViewType(i));
                adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, i);
                holder.itemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                holder.itemView.layout(0, 0, holder.itemView.getMeasuredWidth(), holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight());
                holder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                holder.itemView.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap drawingCache = holder.itemView.getDrawingCache();
                if (drawingCache != null) {

                    bitmaCache.put(String.valueOf(i), drawingCache);
                }
//                holder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
//                holder.itemView.destroyDrawingCache();
                height += holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            bigBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas bigCanvas = new Canvas(bigBitmap);
            bigCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmaCache.get(String.valueOf(i));
                bigCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, iHeight, paint);
                iHeight += bitmap.getHeight();
                bitmap.recycle();
            }

        }
        return bigBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. You saved my life bro!

Comment: Thanks for the code, but imageView is not getting exported

Comment: they very much thanks, one more point can we add mobile frame with that

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
        at .adapter.InsightsDetailAdapter.onBindViewHolder(InsightsDetailAdapter.java:170)
        at .ui.insights.insightdetail.InsightsDetailFragment.getScreenshotFromRecyclerView(InsightsDetailFragment.java:456)

Comment: Better solution than the first accepted one. The accepted solution on top creates a low quality image with missing data.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference.....

---on this line---

                 Bitmap bitmap = bitmaCache.get(String.valueOf(i));

Answer (score 19):

Here is my solution for `LinearLayoutManager` when **all the items are on same size** and there is **only one type of item**. This solution is based on [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956881/4874829).

**Note**: It can possibly lead to out of memory error.

```java
public static Bitmap getRecyclerViewScreenshot(RecyclerView view) {
        int size = view.getAdapter().getItemCount();
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = view.getAdapter().createViewHolder(view, 0);
        view.getAdapter().onBindViewHolder(holder, 0);
        holder.itemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        holder.itemView.layout(0, 0, holder.itemView.getMeasuredWidth(), holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight());
        Bitmap bigBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight() * size,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas bigCanvas = new Canvas(bigBitmap);
        bigCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int iHeight = 0;
        holder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        holder.itemView.buildDrawingCache();
        bigCanvas.drawBitmap(holder.itemView.getDrawingCache(), 0f, iHeight, paint);
        holder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        holder.itemView.destroyDrawingCache();
        iHeight += holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight();
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            view.getAdapter().onBindViewHolder(holder, i);
            holder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            holder.itemView.buildDrawingCache();
            bigCanvas.drawBitmap(holder.itemView.getDrawingCache(), 0f, iHeight, paint);
            iHeight += holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight();
            holder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            holder.itemView.destroyDrawingCache();
        }
        return bigBitmap;
    }
```

**Note 2:** It has originally been written in Kotlin. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24132917/) is the original code used by me.

Comment: Making it to work where not all the items have same size would require you to save the data for each item, probably on a file.

Comment: My one textview is not coming in screenshot

Comment: The Kotlin code in the link uses the async library from https://github.com/metalabdesign/AsyncAwait

Comment: @dmathewwws Actually it is based on old version of `Anko` (before async was reserved word). `AsyncAwait` can be used for that, but actually every async library can work here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Yoav

Comment: I've updated the snippet, so now it uses modern Kotlin syntax.

Answer (score 9):

Take the Screenshot of complete Recyclerview regardless of its items and item types:

This piece of code works like a charm.

Here is a clean way to do this short and precise:

```
recyclerView.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(recyclerView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(recyclerView.getWidth(), recyclerView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
recyclerView.draw(new Canvas(bm));

saveImage(bm);
ImageView im
          = new ImageView(getActivity());
im.setImageBitmap(bm);
 new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(im).show();
```

Comment: Works well. One thing I would like to do is remove the white space above and below. I've tried removing all padding and margin but no luck.

Comment: Try giving background to the layout

Comment: Two thing I had to do: Call recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0) before creating the bitmap to remove the bottom space and ensure consistent output. I also had another view group above the recyclerView which I had to create as a separate bitmap of and combine the two together.

Comment: my screenshot gets a black background for the rows that are out of visible area. Any  suggestion to fix it?

Comment: yeah it do budddy. @J.Dragon

Comment: What about horizontal recycleview ?

Answer (score 1):

**The best solution I found is**

1. create a new NestedScrollView
2. add it to recyclerview's parent
3. remove recyclerview from its parent "it's important to add it to a new parent"
4. add recyclerview to nestedscrollview
5. take screenshot of nestedscrollview
6. add recyclerview to its main parent.

   ```
    nestedScreenShot = new NestedScrollView(getContext());

    constraintLayout.removeView(recyclerView);

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params =new 

    Constraints.LayoutParams(viewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    nestedScreenShot.setLayoutParams(params);

   Drawable scrollBackground = scrollView.getBackground();
   if (scrollBackground != null) {
       tempNestedScreenShot.setBackground(scrollBackground);
   }
   tempNestedScreenShot.setPadding(scrollView.getLeft(), 
   scrollView.getTop(), scrollView.getRight(), scrollView.getBottom());

    constraintLayout.addView(nestedScreenShot);

    nestedScreenShot.addView(recyclerView, params);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {

               nestedScreenShot.removeView(recyclerView);
               constraintLayout.removeView(nestedScreenShot);
               nestedScreenShot = null;
               constraintLayout.addView(recyclerView, params);


           }
           }, 8000);
     takescreenshotOfNested(nestedScreenShot);
   ```

This method will return screenshot of nestedscrollview

```
       private Bitmap takescreenshotOfNested(View u) {
        
        NestedScrollView viewNested = null;
            
        ScrollView viewScroll = null;
              
        if (u instanceof NestedScrollView) {
                 
       
        viewNested = (NestedScrollView) u;
             
     
       } else if (u instanceof ScrollView) {
              
      
         viewScroll = (ScrollView) u;
            
       }
            
                Bitmap bitmap;
                if (viewNested != null) {
                    viewNested.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                    viewNested.invalidate();
                    viewNested.getChildAt(0).setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                    viewNested.getChildAt(0).invalidate();
            
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewNested.getChildAt(0).getWidth(),
                            viewNested.getChildAt(0).getHeight() + 8, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                    canvas.drawColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.layout_background));
                    viewNested.draw(canvas);
                } else {
            
                    try {
            
                        viewScroll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                        viewScroll.invalidate();
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }
                    viewScroll.getChildAt(0).setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                    viewScroll.getChildAt(0).invalidate();
            
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewScroll.getChildAt(0).getWidth(),
                            viewScroll.getChildAt(0).getHeight() + 8, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                    canvas.drawColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.layout_background));
                    viewScroll.draw(canvas);
            
                }
                return bitmap;
            
            }
```

> don't forget to recycle the bitmap after using it

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method to get a screenshot of a few different views:

```
private static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    if (view.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        view = getNextView(view);
        Log.d(TAG, "New view id: " + view.getId());
    }
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap;
    if (view instanceof ScrollView) {
        returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(0).getWidth(), ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(0).getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } else if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        view.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } else {
        returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null) {
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    } else {
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}

/**
 * If the base view is not visible, then it has no width or height.
 * This causes a problem when we are creating a PDF based on its size.
 * This method gets the next visible View.
 *
 * @param view The invisible view
 * @return The next visible view after the given View, or the original view if there's no more
 * visible views.
 */
private static View getNextView(View view) {
    if (view.getParent() != null && (view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        View child;
        boolean getNext = false;
        //Iterate through all views from parent
        for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
            child = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (getNext) {
                //Make sure the view is visible, else iterate again until we find a visible view
                if (child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "CHILD: %s : %s", child.getClass().getSimpleName(), child.getId()));
                    view = child;
                }
            }
            //Iterate until we find out current view,
            // then we want to get the NEXT view
            if (child.getId() == view.getId()) {
                getNext = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from Nouman Ch answer, that solution works great, but I am facing background color issue in final image and recyclerView scrolling also not working fine after that. Here is quick fix!

After creating the bitmap from recyclerView

```
presenter?.dataRecyclerView?.let {
            it.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(it.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            );

            var bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                it.width,
                it.measuredHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            it.draw(Canvas(bm))

//to fix background color of final image
            val newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.width, bm.height, bm.config)
            val canvas = Canvas(newBitmap)
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
            canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0f, 0f, null)
            bm = newBitmap

            saveBitmapeToGallery(bm)
//notify adapter, to fix scrolling
            it.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This class generates a `Bitmap` for a `LinearLayout` containing views and a `RecyclerView`.

This is based on Prasham's answer, but refactored to **Kotlin** and descriptive methods to make it *easier to understand*.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.LruCache
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
import androidx.core.view.children
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class BitmapComposer {

    private val maxMemory by lazy {
        (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024).toInt()
    }

    // Use 1/7 of the available memory for this memory cache
    private val cacheSize by lazy {
        maxMemory / 7
    }

    private val bitmapCache: LruCache<Int, Bitmap> by lazy {
        LruCache(cacheSize)
    }

    // Increments each time something gets added to the LruCache
    private var cacheIndex = 0

    // Accumulated height to be used as the total
    private var bigHeight = 0

    fun getViewAsBitmap(view: View): Bitmap {
        if (view is LinearLayoutCompat) {
            view.children.forEach {
                addViewToBitmapCache(it)
            }
        } else if (view is RecyclerView) {
            addRecyclerViewToBitmapCache(view)
        }

        return drawBigBitmap(view)
    }

    private fun drawBigBitmap(view: View): Bitmap {
        val bigBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            view.measuredWidth,
            bigHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )

        val bigCanvas = Canvas(bigBitmap)
        bigCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)

        val paint = Paint()
        var top = 0

        for (i in 0 until bitmapCache.size()) {
            val bitmap: Bitmap = bitmapCache.get(i)
            bigCanvas.drawBitmap(
                bitmap,
                0f, // left
                top.toFloat(), // top
                paint
            )

            top += bitmap.height
            bitmap.recycle()
        }

        return bigBitmap
    }

    private fun addRecyclerViewToBitmapCache(view: RecyclerView) {
        val adapter = view.adapter ?: throw Exception("No adapter found")
        val size = adapter.itemCount

        for (i in 0 until size) {
            val itemView = getItemView(view, adapter, i)
            addViewToBitmapCache(itemView)
        }
    }

    private fun addViewToBitmapCache(view: View) {
        if (view is RecyclerView) {
            addRecyclerViewToBitmapCache(view)
            return
        }

        val drawingCache = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            view.width,
            view.height,
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
        )

        val canvas = Canvas(drawingCache)
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)

        view.draw(canvas)
        bitmapCache.put(cacheIndex++, drawingCache)
        bigHeight += view.measuredHeight
    }

    private fun getItemView(
        view: RecyclerView,
        adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>,
        i: Int
    ): View {
        val holder = adapter.createViewHolder(view, adapter.getItemViewType(i))
        adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, i)

        holder.itemView.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        )

        holder.itemView.layout(
            0,
            0,
            holder.itemView.measuredWidth,
            holder.itemView.measuredHeight
        )

        return holder.itemView
    }
}
```

**How to use it?**

Simply pass a view (it can be a `LinearLayoutCompat` or a `RecyclerView`).

```
val composer = BitmapComposer()
val bitmap = composer.getViewAsBitmap(view)
```

Notes:

- In order to **center elements** (e.g. `TextView`s), I used `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:gravity="center"` as a workaround.
- I haven't tested with other `ViewGroup`s, but works fine for a `LinearLayout` containing a `RecyclerView` and other simple views.