# create PDF of RecyclerView in FULL length

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf-generation, android-recyclerview

I want to create a PDF of "full page" of the activity. The view contains a RecyclerView with many items.

I can take a full dimensions of my Recyclerview but the file is drawed only of the current view. This is my code:

```
    public void tela (){ // create a new document
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)

    {
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        getScreenshotFromRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
        content = mRecyclerView;
        content.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#303030"));


        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(wil,
                height, 1).create();

    // create a new page from the PageInfo
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

    // repaint the user's text into the page
        content.draw(page.getCanvas());

    // do final processing of the page
        document.finishPage(page);

    // saving pdf document to sdcard
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy - HH-mm-ss",Locale.getDefault());
        String pdfName = "Revisões_"
                + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".pdf";

    // all created files will be saved at path /sdcard/PDFDemo_AndroidSRC/
        File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), pdfName);

        try {
            outputFile.createNewFile();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            document.writeTo(out);
            document.close();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(this,"PDF gerado com sucesso",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("Gerou", "pdf");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

// getting the limits

```
    public void getScreenshotFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView view) {
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = view.getAdapter();
    if (adapter != null) {
        int size = adapter.getItemCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = adapter.createViewHolder(view, adapter.getItemViewType(i));
            adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, i);
            holder.itemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            holder.itemView.layout(0, 0, holder.itemView.getMeasuredWidth(), holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight());
            height += holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        wil=view.getMeasuredWidth();


    }
}
```

The result is this:
[image]

Can I create the pdf with the all values of my Recyclerview?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented a helper class to handle image saving to PDF. In the method saveImageToPDF() I pass:

- a TabLayout, which is above my recyclerView
- the Bitmap of the recyclerView
- the Context

to get the recyclerView Bitmap I used this [Take a screenshot of RecyclerView in FULL length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085063/take-a-screenshot-of-recyclerview-in-full-length)

```
public class PDFHelper {

    private File mFolder;
    private File mFile;
    private Context mContext;

    public PDFHelper(File folder, Context context) {

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mFolder = folder;

        if(!mFolder.exists())
            mFolder.mkdirs();
    }

    public void saveImageToPDF(View title, Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

        mFile = new File(mFolder, filename + ".pdf");
        if (!mFile.exists()) {
            int height = title.getHeight() + bitmap.getHeight();
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), height, 1).create();
            PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
            Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
            title.draw(canvas);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new Rect(0, title.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight()), null);

            document.finishPage(page);

            try {
                mFile.createNewFile();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                document.writeTo(out);
                document.close();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a more simpler way to do it. I am not sure if my code is clean or is this the right way to do it. I had a recycler view with variable size. I wanted to print the whole length of the recycler view in pdf. Also I use IText Pdf just for reference.

Things that I did.
Below is the XML file for the single item in the recycler view. Please note that I have given an ID to the card view as I used card view (You can use any that you want as the root, LinearLayout or RelativeLayout etc.)android:id="@+id/preview_order_list_card_root"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/preview_order_list_card_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/car"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:text="12"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preview_car_name"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preview_car_model"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preview_part_name"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preview_part_model"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:text="12"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/car_part"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preview_quantity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preview_quantity_bucket"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/preview_extra_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preview_ordered_from"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preview_list_price"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/preview_list_less"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now in your adapter just create an arraylist with getters and setters that will save the card view object when ever it calls onBindViewHolder is called as below.

```
private static ArrayList<CardView> cardViewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PreviewOrderAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        OrderItemDetailsModel orderItemDetailsModel = namesArrList.get(position);
        holder.orderedFrom.setText(orderItemDetailsModel.getOrderedFrom());
        holder.listPrice.setText(orderItemDetailsModel.getListPrice());
        holder.listLess.setText(orderItemDetailsModel.getListLess());

        // ADDING THE CARD VIEW OBJECT IN THE ARRAYLIST
        addCardView(holder.cardView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return namesArrList.size();
    }

    private static void addCardView(CardView cardView)
    {
        cardViewArrayList.add(cardView);
    }

    public static ArrayList<CardView> getCardViewList()
    {
        return cardViewArrayList;
    }
```

Now finally, while printing the recycler views do this.

```
//Getting the card view array list from the adapter above
ArrayList<CardView> cardViewArrayList = adapter.getCardViewList();
                for (int i = 0; i < cardViewArrayList.size(); i++)
                {
                    // Iterate till the last of the array list and add each view individually to the document.
                    addContent(document, cardViewArrayList.get(i));
                }

//Adding the content to the document
private void addContent(Document document, View view)
            throws DocumentException
    {
        try
        {
            view.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bmp = view.getDrawingCache();

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            image.scalePercent(70);
            image.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
            document.add(image);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("TAG-ORDER PRINT ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

By this way we dont have to worry about memory leaks due to the large size of the recycler view as we are adding each view separately to the document.

Comment: Some how i managed to work out your idea and it was a successful attempt   , but there is a problem . Only visible cells from the recyclerview is showing in saved PDF file . Did you encounter any issue like that .