# How do I take screenshot or save as image my fragment app in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have recently made an app memegenerator
screenshot : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzeQO.png)

I want whenever I click on the button to create meme
it should automatically save that picture below (which is a fragment)
How do I do that I have no idea?

This is what I found on internet to place in my code

Should I add this on my mainactivity file or the fragment java file

` public void createBitmap()
    {
        //Log.d(Const.DEBUG,"Creating a Bitmap");

```
    Bitmap bmp;

    ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup)((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());

    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator);
    File file = new File(directory,"DankMeme");

    try{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    v.destroyDrawingCache();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

}`
```

**update This my fragment code **

```
public class BottomSectionFragment extends Fragment {
private static TextView topMemeText;
private static TextView bottomMemeText;
private View view;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_picture_fragment,container,false);
    topMemeText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.topMemeText);
    bottomMemeText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bottomMemeText);

    return view;
}
public void setMemeText(String top,String bottom)
{
    topMemeText.setText(top);
    bottomMemeText.setText(bottom);
    //createBitmap();
    // I am calling tackeAndSaveScreenshot func here because when user press button it comes to this func
    // to change text and right after I want screenshot
    tackeAndSaveScreenShot();
}

//Screenshot
public void tackeAndSaveScreenShot() {
    View MainView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
    MainView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    MainView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap MainBitmap = MainView.getDrawingCache();
    Rect frame = new Rect();

    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
    //to remove statusBar from the taken sc
    int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
    //using screen size to create bitmap
    int width = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    Bitmap OutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(MainBitmap, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height - statusBarHeight);
    MainView.destroyDrawingCache();
    try {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        //you can also using current time to generate name
        String name="YourName";
        File file = new File(path, name + ".png");
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        OutBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

        //this line will add the saved picture to gallery
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421252/taking-screenshot-of-linearlayout-and-recyclerview/45434407?noredirect=1#comment77846503_45434407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will take screenshot from your mobile screen. you can change the MainView to your view that you want to take screenshot from.

Don't forget to add "Write external storage" permission to manifest

```
public void tackeAndSaveScreenShot(Activity mActivity) {
    View MainView = mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    MainView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    MainView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap MainBitmap = MainView.getDrawingCache();
    Rect frame = new Rect();

    mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
    //to remove statusBar from the taken sc
    int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
    //using screen size to create bitmap 
    int width = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    Bitmap OutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(MainBitmap, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height - statusBarHeight);
    MainView.destroyDrawingCache();
    try {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        //you can also using current time to generate name
        String name="YourName";
        File file = new File(path, name + ".png");
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        OutBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

        //this line will add the saved picture to gallery
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

calling method by using :

```
Button memeDanke = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.memeDanke);
memeDanke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             tackeAndSaveScreenShot(getActivity());
        }
    });
```

Comment: so I should copy this code and place it in my fragment java file and the only thing to change here is the view? is it?

Comment: yes. just copy this code in your java class or fragment. you can change the view and customize the sizes. if you are using it in fragment use getActivity() for required params @AmirAli

Comment: use this :   mActivity.getContentResolver(); @AmirAli

Comment: but I have edited that because I can't pass any argument I want the screenshot when someone press to dank meme text

Comment: can u provide the call to function? should I call it in oncreateview?

Comment: you should using OnClickListener  . i will update my answer @AmirAli

Comment: I have updated my post and added the fragment code 
Kindly check

Comment: so where is problem?

Comment: it is not taking any screenshot

Comment: its work for me. be sure is added write external storage in manifest @AmirAli