# Android 11 can't take full screenshot scrollview

Tags: android, screenshot

I have an activity, Receipt, in which I want to take full screenshot of a scrollview. However, in android 11 (tested on a Google Pixel 2), this code doesn't work for me:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(scrollview, scrollview.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), scrollview.getChildAt(0).getWidth());

//create bitmap from the ScrollView 
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int height, int width) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

The screenshot works, but not it's not a full screenshot.

Comment: Related: [Take a screenshot of RecyclerView in FULL length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30085063/295004)