# Converting a ListView to Bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, bitmap

I want to convert a ListView to a bitmap image.
The following code works fine, except in cases where the list is longer then the screen. I managed to get the canvas to the desired size, but it still shows only the elements that fit in the screen and the other area is just white:

```
fun getBitmapFromView(view: ListView): Bitmap {
    val listAdapter = view.adapter
    var totalHeight = listView.paddingTop + listView.paddingBottom
    val desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.width, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
    for (i in 0 until listAdapter.getCount()) {
        val listItem: View = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView)
        if (listItem != null) {
            listItem.layoutParams =
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            totalHeight += listItem.measuredHeight
        }
    }

    val bitmap  = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, totalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap )
    val bgDrawable = view.background
    if (bgDrawable != null) bgDrawable.draw(canvas) else canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
    view.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

How can I fix it to contain the whole list?

Comment: Have you tried to change to `Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)`

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Yeah, it just makes a screenshot with the visible content only, not the entire list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085063/take-a-screenshot-of-recyclerview-in-full-length can check here if it is helping

Comment: Thank you @TicherhazFreePalestineThe! I adjusted it to my case.

Comment: Nice. good to you. You are welcome. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 fun getBitmapFromView(listView: ListView): Bitmap {
        val listAdapter = listView.adapter
        var totalHeight = listView.paddingTop + listView.paddingBottom
        val desiredWidth = listView.width
        for (i in 0 until listAdapter.count) {
            val childView = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView)
            val widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            childView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            childView.layout(0, 0, childView.measuredWidth, childView.measuredHeight)
            totalHeight += childView.measuredHeight
        }

        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(listView.width, totalHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        var topDrawDistance = 0
        for (i in 0 until listAdapter.count) {
            val childView = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView)
            val widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            childView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            val childBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(childView.measuredWidth, childView.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val childCanvas = Canvas(childBitmap)
            childView.layout(0, 0, childView.measuredWidth, childView.measuredHeight)
            childView.draw(childCanvas)
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                childBitmap,
                Rect(0, 0, childView.measuredWidth, childView.measuredHeight),
                Rect(0, topDrawDistance, childView.measuredWidth, topDrawDistance + childView.measuredHeight),
                Paint()
            )
            topDrawDistance += childView.measuredHeight
        }
        return bitmap
    }
```

Things to notice:

1. ListView is not recommended anymore, RecyclerView is newer version for list creation.
2. If you want to draw whole list, you have to draw each item separately as items below screen are not rendered yet.
3. You need to call `layout()` function
4. Drawing background of parent view is useless as it's height is equal to screen height.
5. When iterating items in adapter use loop variable `i` instead of static `0`

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get it to work by adjusting the code in [Take a screenshot of RecyclerView in FULL length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085063/take-a-screenshot-of-recyclerview-in-full-length) for ListView in Kotlin. Thanks for your help.

```
fun getBitmapFromView(listView: ListView): Bitmap? {
    val adapter: ListAdapter = listView.adapter
    var bigBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    if (adapter != null) {
        val size = adapter.count
        var height = 0
        val paint = Paint()
        var iHeight = 0
        val maxMemory = (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024).toInt()

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        val cacheSize = maxMemory / 8
        val bitmapCache = LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize)

        for (i in 0 until size) {
            val itemView = adapter.getView(i, null, listView) as View
            itemView.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            )
            itemView.layout(0, 0, itemView.measuredWidth, itemView.measuredHeight)
            itemView.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
            itemView.buildDrawingCache()
            val drawingCache = itemView.drawingCache

            if (drawingCache != null) {
                bitmapCache.put(i.toString(), drawingCache)
            }
            height += itemView.measuredHeight
        }

        bigBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(listView.width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val bigCanvas = Canvas(bigBitmap)
        bigCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)

        for (i in 0 until size) {
            val bitmap = bitmapCache.get(i.toString())
            bigCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, iHeight.toFloat(), paint)
            iHeight += bitmap?.height ?: 0
            bitmap?.recycle()
        }
    }
    return bigBitmap
}
```