# How to take bitmap from a linear layout in full height

Tags: android, bitmap, android-linearlayout

I have a rather long `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`, and I have to scroll to view all of this `LinearLayout`. I want to know how to get a `Bitmap` of `LinearLayout` in full height, not the max height of the screen.

There was something similar in this post :
[Android get screenshot of all ListView items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742343/android-get-screenshot-of-all-listview-items)

In my case, I want to do it with `LinearLayout`, not `ListView`

Comment: Post your layout.  If its in a ScrollView, and the ImageView is wrap_content then it should be the right height.  It may not be the correct width though.

Comment: There is many item in the LinearLayout, not only ImageView. Just consider LinearLayout as a View, then I want to take screenshot of this View in its full height, something like that. Thanks :)