# Get bitmap of linear layout with RecyclerView inside in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have LinearLayout with some detail and it has RecyclerView  in it

```
LinearLayout
 |
 Some Information in LinearLayout
 |   
 RecyclerView
```

I am getting bitmap of LinearLayout using this code

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) { // view is linearlayout
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

I am successfully getting Image of view but recycler view is getting cut . It does not capture all detail that is in recycler view container .

Is it possible to capture bitmap of linear layout with all the row detail of recyclerview?

Comment: If you mean you want to capture all of the items in the `RecyclerView`, including the ones off-screen, you can't do it with that code. You'll have to do something like is shown for `ListView` in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742343/android-get-screenshot-of-all-listview-items).

Comment: yes and also linearlayout detail not only recyclerview . I will check this post